# Relative change of page dimensions with geometry

Tags: margins, geometry

When using the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) package, how do I change parameters in **relative amounts**?

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
\newgeometry{top=top+2cm, bottom=bottom+2cm}
```

which increases the top and bottom margins by `2cm` respectively. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you add the `layout` package in the preamble, then the `\layout` macro will draw a picture of the various settings, you could then use these setting to compute the appropriate values (needs [the `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc)): `\newgeometry{top=1.0in+\voffset+2.0cm\relax}`

Comment: The length of `bottom` is save in the macro `\Gm@bmargin` so you can use `bottom=\dimexpr\Gm@bmargin+2cm\relax`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Will probably wreck havoc to `\texheight` and get hundrends of underfull boxes:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Really. Was untested ;-)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: That works: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\clearpage
\makeatletter
\edef\tempa{\dimexpr\Gm@bmargin+2cm\relax}
\makeatother
\newgeometry{bottom=\tempa}
\kant[1]
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\kant[1]
\end{document}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It is highly unlikely that the 2cm will end up in a number of lines that are exactly divisible by `\baselineskip`, but maybe you caught geometry at the point where it is busy with adjustments.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Your are right. I think that can be handled too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that no such facility is provided by `geometry`. You cannot specify the `top` using `top=top+2cm` or the `bottom` using `bottom=bottom+2`.

When you want to increase the top by 2cm, presumably without affecting the `headheight` or the `headsep` lengths, you can do this by changing the `topmargin`.

```
 \addtolength{topmargin}{2cm}
```

However, in general I would advice against all these, unless you really study how the page geometry is constructed. Normally LaTeX and packages start from the `paperheight`, subtract values for the head parameters, estimate a `textheight` that is an exact multiple of `\baselineskip` and then position the `\footskip`.

Recommendation use `memoir` or `scrbook` and read Chapter 2 of the memoir manual.